# Hive - Regex wrong arguments

Tags: regex, hive

I need to capture the string after text 'lnk=' in the url pattern but the regex throws an error.

```
select regexp_extract('www.mysite.com?lnk=snav_rd_clothing&param=homepage', '(?<=(lnk=))(.*?)(?=\&|\?|$)') from table1 limit 10;

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments ''(?<=(lnk=))(.*?)(?=\&|\?|$)'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)  on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract@65c86db8 of class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract with arguments {www.mysite.com?lnk=snav_rd_clothing&param=homepage:java.lang.String, (?<=(lnk=))(.*?)(?=&|?|$):java.lang.String} of size 2
```

Comment: I suspect you just need `regexp_extract(str, '[?&]lnk=([^&?]*)', 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you escaped `?` and `&` with a single backslash. Since the string literals in hive support escape sequences, you need to double backslashes to pass a literal backslash to the regex engine.

However, your pattern is overcomplicated for the current task, namely, get 0+ chars other than `&` and `?` after `lnk=`.

You may rely on a capturing groups only here and a negated character class:

```
regexp_extract(str, '[?&]lnk=([^&?]*)', 1)
```

where `1` means the first (and the only one here) capturing group.

**Details**:

- `[?&]` - a `?` or `&` (to match `lnk` as a query param name)
- `lnk=` - `a literal substring`lnk=`
- `([^&?]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `&` and `?` (the `[^...]` is a *negated character class* that matches any char other than the one defined in the set/ranges)